# returning a value from asynchronous call using semaphores

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I need to use `NSURLSession` to make network calls. On the basis of certain things, after I receive the response, I need to return an `NSError` object.

I am using semaphores to make the asynchronous call behave synchronously.
The problem is, the err is set properly inside call, but as soon as semaphore ends (after

dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

), the `err` becomes nil.

Please help

**Code:**

```
-(NSError*)loginWithEmail:(NSString*)email Password:(NSString*)password
{
    NSError __block *err = NULL;

        // preparing the URL of login
        NSURL *Url              =       [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

        NSData *PostData        =       [Post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        // preparing the request object
        NSMutableURLRequest *Request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [Request setURL:Url];
        [Request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [Request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [Request setHTTPBody:PostData];

        NSMutableDictionary __block *parsedData = NULL; // holds the data after it is parsed

        dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        config.TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol = kTLSProtocol11;

        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];

        NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:Request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response1, NSError *err){
                if(!data)
                {
                    err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Connection Timeout" code:200 userInfo:nil];
                }
                else
                {
                    NSString *formattedData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                    NSLog(@"%@", formattedData);

                    if([formattedData rangeOfString:@"<!DOCTYPE"].location != NSNotFound || [formattedData rangeOfString:@"<html"].location != NSNotFound)
                    {
                        loginSuccessful = NO;
                        //*errorr = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Server Issue" code:201 userInfo:nil];
                        err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Server Issue" code:201 userInfo:nil];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];
                        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [parsedData objectForKey:@"User"];

                        loginSuccessful = YES;
                }
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        }];
        [task resume];

        // but have the thread wait until the task is done

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    return err;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest cutting the Gordian knot: You should not use semaphores to make an asynchronous method behave synchronously. Adopt asynchronous patterns, e.g. use a completion handler:

```
- (void)loginWithEmail:(NSString *)email password:(NSString*)password completionHandler:(void (^ __nonnull)(NSDictionary *userDictionary, NSError *error))completionHandler
{
    NSString *post   = ...; // build your `post` here, making sure to percent-escape userid and password if this is x-www-form-urlencoded request
    
    NSURL  *url      = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    // [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];                       // not needed to set length ... this is done for you
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];  // but it is best practice to set the `Content-Type`; use whatever `Content-Type` appropriate for your request
    [request setValue:@"text/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];                                // and it's also best practice to also inform server of what sort of response you'll accept
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    config.TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol = kTLSProtocol11;
    
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
    
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *err) {
        if (!data) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                completionHandler(nil, [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Connection Timeout" code:200 userInfo:nil]);
            });
        } else {
            NSError *parseError;
            NSDictionary *parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&parseError];
            
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (parsedData) {
                    NSDictionary *dict = parsedData[@"User"];
                    completionHandler(dict, nil);
                } else {
                    completionHandler(nil, [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Server Issue" code:201 userInfo:nil]);
                }
            });
        }
    }];
    [task resume];
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
[self loginWithEmail:userid password:password completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *userDictionary, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // do whatever you want on error here
    } else {
        // successful, use `userDictionary` here
    }
}];

// but don't do anything reliant on successful login here; put it inside the block above
```

Note:

1. I know you're going to object to restoring this back to asynchronous method, but it's a really bad idea to make this synchronous. First it's a horrible UX (the app will freeze and the user won't know if it's really doing something or whether it's dead) and if you're on a slow network you can have all sorts of problems (e.g. the watchdog process can kill your app if you do this at the wrong time).

   So, keep this asynchronous. Ideally, show `UIActivityIndicatorView` before starting asynchronous login, and turn it off in the `completionHandler`. The `completionHandler` would also initiate the next step in the process (e.g. `performSegueWithIdentifier`).
2. I don't bother testing for HTML content; it is easier to just attempt parse JSON and see if it succeeds or not. You'll also capture a broader array of errors this way.
3. Personally, I wouldn't return my own error objects. I'd just go ahead and return the error objects the OS gave to me. That way, if the caller had to differentiate between different error codes (e.g. no connection vs server error), you could.

   And if you use your own error codes, I'd suggest not varying the `domain`. The `domain` should cover a whole category of errors (e.g. perhaps one custom domain for all of your app's own internal errors), not vary from one error to another. It's not good practice to use the `domain` field for something like error messages. If you want something more descriptive in your `NSError` object, put the text of the error message inside the `userInfo` dictionary.
4. I might suggest method/variable names to conform to Cocoa naming conventions (e.g. classes start with uppercase letter, variables and method names and parameters start with lowercase letter).
5. There's no need to set `Content-Length` (that's done for you), but it is good practice to set `Content-Type` and `Accept` (though not necessary).

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out weak points in my code. I am grateful..!! Will now change my code to adapt asynchronous behavior...

Answer (score 4):

Rob's answer tells you how to do it right, but not what mistake you made:

You have two variables named err, which are totally unrelated. It seems that you haven't turned on some important warnings, otherwise your code wouldn't even have compiled.

The parameter err that is passed to your completion block is the error from the URL request. You replace it without thinking with a timeout error - so the true error is now lost. Consider that timeout is not the only error.

But all the errors that you set only set the local variable err which was passed to you in the completion block; they never touch the variable err in the caller at all.

PS. Several serious errors in your JSON handling. JSON can come in UTF-16 or UTF-32, in which case formattedData will be nil and you incorrectly print "Server Issue". If the data isn't JSON there is no guarantee that it contains DOCTYPE or html, that test is absolute rubbish. Your user with the nickname JoeSmith will hate you.

Passing NSJSONReadingAllowFragments to NSJSONSerialization is nonsense. dict is not mutable; if you try to modify it your app will crash. You don't check that the parser returned a dictionary, you don't check that there is a value for the key "User", and you don't check that the value is a dictionary. That's lots of ways how your app can crash.

Comment: Excellent catch. I didn't see that he redefined `err`.

Comment: Thank you so much.. That was really a silly thing I did. That straightened out my problem.. However.. Now I will not use semaphore anymore. Will accept asynchronous behavior as it is meant to be.. +1 for you.. thanks a tonne..

Answer (score 1):

You need to let the compiler know that you will be modifying `err`. It needs some special handling to preserve that beyond the life of the block. Declare it with `__block`:

```
__block NSError *err = NULL;
```

See [Blocks and Variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html) in Blocks Programming Topics for more details.

Comment: Tried that.. Still does not work.. It returns nil even then